# DirectX technique to render wingtip vortices

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, render

Say if I wanted to create a 3D airplane game and I want to create this special visual effect where the plane wing's create vortices (where it has this line/string coming off the tip of the airplane's wings), how do I go about doing this? I thought about using a very small quad texture (of a white fading effect dot) and output it like particles very close to each other to make it look like its in a line, but I think this will be a bad idea? Is there a better solution to this?

something like this:[link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=homeworld%202&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=Kk9mPoA_ZkerCM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcQ-0M8DBxedf9aJ938NCWbyvenpnC1ockTtkg6nQFMy27TQbXJv%253B1600%253B1200%253BlfEeCM9pC1lOyM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fthemodernmage.com%25252Fgearbox-announces-hd-remakes-of-homeworld-1-2&source=iu&usg=__Pvuj29kIxQ96pnmh0PeEpxKzNxs=&sa=X&ei=_1ECU-OuEcurhAepxoDACw&ved=0CEUQ9QEwBQ&biw=1454&bih=867#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Kk9mPoA_ZkerCM%253A;lfEeCM9pC1lOyM;http%253A%252F%252Fthemodernmage.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F07%252Fhomeworld_2_wallpaper_3-normal.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fthemodernmage.com%252Fgearbox-announces-hd-remakes-of-homeworld-1-2;1600;1200)

Comment: You could use a set of billboards as the carrier geometry and use an appropriate pixel shader to render the curve.

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/classOgre_1_1RibbonTrail.html for inspiration.  This uses billboards as @NicoSchertler suggests by the look of it.

Comment: +1 to billboards (a sprites that is always facing the viewer). Generate quads in geometry shader and texturize or colorize procedurally in pixel shader.